# Process consecutive messages

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream of object coordinates (time, x, y), I want to transform it into a stream of distances and then to a stream of speeds. To do it I need to process two consecutive messages each time.

Can you give me an idea on how to create a stream of Euclidean distances between points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataStream<Distance> distances = yourCoordinateSource
            .windowAll(GlobalWindows.create())
            .trigger(PurgingTrigger.of(CountTrigger.of(2)))
            .process(new DistanceFunction());

DataStream<Speed> speeds = distances.map(new SpeedFunction())...
```

You can chain process `DataStream`s.

To access two messages you can create fixed size windows of 2 messages, then apply a processing function to the window.

Assuming your stream is not keyed use `windowAll()`.

You have to implement both `DistanceFunction` (extends `ProcessWindowFunction`) and `SpeedFunction` (Extends `MapFunction`).

Comment: But how is it possible to implement map which two different messages? I need to calc euclidean distance between points.

Comment: @szu you have to pass two different map functions.

Comment: E.g. I have the messages (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). Distance will be d1 = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) So map function should have access to *different* messages somehow? Looks like I need something like sliding window or shifted stream to do it?

Comment: Nice answer by @Beckham. Two minor comments about it.  First, using `windowAll` forces a parallelism of 1, so you should use a keyed stream if at all possible. Second, it assumes events are always ordered correctly (by the `time` field), though I can't think of a super-easy way to make out-of-order work without writing a custom ProcessFunction.

Comment: @szu if it works you might select this as the best answer.